# CompositeCollection добавить один элемент

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Хочу сделать так:

```
<CompositeCollection>
    <Binding Path="Tree"/>
</CompositeCollection>
```

Получаю исключение:

"Binding нельзя использовать в коллекции "CompositeCollection". "Binding" можно задать только в параметре DependencyProperty объекта DependencyObject.

Tree - это не коллекция, поэтому добавить его через CollectionContainer тоже нельзя.

В коде, кстати, один элемент Tree запросто добавляется в CompositeCollection, но мне надо в xaml сделать.

Или подскажите шаблон для вывода бинарного дерева в WPF.

Comment: Класс предназначен для коллекций. Нужен один элемент - добавляйте коллекцию на один элемент. Хотя, можно попробовать добавить внутрь  просто `ListBoxItem`.

Comment: _"Binding нельзя использовать в коллекции "CompositeCollection""_ -- но можно в CollectionContainer, так: `<CompositeCollection><CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Path=Tree}" /></CompositeCollection>`

Comment: @Monk, его функционал позволяет добавить туда любые элементы. Так сказано в документации.

Comment: @Stack, а вы пробовали сами?

Comment: @iRumba ну так и добавьте `ListBoxItem` с нужным вам биндингом.